# Aliases work in Access but not SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, alias

I have a query that used to work beautifully in MS Access that I am trying to bring over to SQL Server as a view.  The problem is two fields that get their value from other views.  These views work perfectly fine.  I am trying to take the two fields and get a percentage rating from them.  The query kind of looks like this:

```
SELECT dbo.v_IPQueryTotal,
   GEOLOC.City,
   GEOLOC.State,
   dbo.v_IPQueryTotal          AS [Total],
   dbo.v_IPHits                AS [Confirmed],
   [Confirmed] / [Total] * 100 AS Percentage
FROM   GEOLOC,
   v_IPQueryTotal;
```

Comment: Your query will not work in either database because `dbo.v_IPQueryTotal` is a table name and not a column name.

Comment: It looks like you're selecting the entire view instead of a field within the view. `dbo.v_IPQueryTotal` should be `dbo.v_IPQueryTotal.SOMETHING`.

Comment: So sorry, wrote it down wrong.  Forgot to include the field, my bad.  So let me give you the corrected code:

Comment: SELECT dbo.v_IPQueryTotal,
   GEOLOC.City,
   GEOLOC.State,
   dbo.v_IPQueryTotal.AllHits          AS [Total],
   dbo.v_IPHits.IPHitCount                AS [Confirmed],
   [Confirmed] / [Total] * 100 AS Percentage
FROM   GEOLOC,
   v_IPQueryTotal;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to refer to column aliases inline within the same statement using SQL Server. You need to reference the columns directly like this:

```
SELECT
    dbo.v_IPQueryTotal,
    GEOLOC.City,
    GEOLOC.State,
    dbo.v_IPQueryTotal.AllHits AS [Total],
    dbo.v_IPHits.IPHitCount AS [Confirmed],
    dbo.v_IPHits.IPHitCount / dbo.v_IPQueryTotal.AllHits * 100 AS Percentage

FROM
    GEOLOC, v_IPQueryTotal
```

Another solution is to use a inner derived table and reference their columns in the outer query:

```
SELECT
    tmp.*,
    tmp.Confirmed / tmp.Total * 100 AS Percentage

FROM
(
    SELECT
        dbo.v_IPQueryTotal,
        GEOLOC.City,
        GEOLOC.State,
        dbo.v_IPQueryTotal.AllHits AS [Total],
        dbo.v_IPHits.IPHitCount AS [Confirmed]

    FROM
        GEOLOC, v_IPQueryTotal
) tmp
```

Actually there is no join condition defined so this results in a cartesian product which may be not what you expect.

Comment: Actually there is a join and the query I am doing is much more complex; I was just having heartburn trying to figure out how to calculate that percentage. :)

Comment: Ah, ok. And just to make it clear for me and others who come across this question: were my suggestions helpful then?

Comment: Yes it certainly was, I was not calling out to the view correctly which in turn caused me grief.